# Parsing weired JSON format

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have to parse `JSON`. I am using Jackson library to parse it.

My code:

```
JSONObject root = (JSONObject)parser.parse(response);
JSONArray users = (JSONArray) root.get("response");
```

Everything would be fine if not a that number in from of elements (1192220) which actually represents a length of a structure. When I am reading it using `root.get("response")` this number appears to be a first element in `users` array. I really don't want that. Of course, I can manually truncate an array, but probably it should a better way of doing it. Any suggestions?

```
{
   "response":[
      1192220,
      {
         "uid":39377403,
         "first_name":"John",
         "last_name":"Smith",
         "screen_name":"Super cool guy",
         "interests":"N/A"
      },
      {
         "uid":19439900,
         "first_name":"Natalie",
         "last_name":"Brook",
         "screen_name":"nutaloveis",
         "interests":"bike"
      },
      {
         "uid":5857176,
         "first_name":"James",
         "last_name":"Mercer",
         "screen_name":"alenkashishkova"
      }, .....]
 }
```

Comment: If you know that it is always there, just remove it from the array.

Comment: I don't see the problem.  But then I've never seen the point in using Jackson -- it seems to create more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Filter it out later

If that number allways is the first element of that array, why dont you just skip it when iterating over the array later on (Start your for-loop at index 1 instead of 0)?

If numbers appear all over the array or at random indexes but you only want to get the objects (e.g. filter out all numbers), you could use javas `instanceof` operator and check whether it is an instance of `JSONObject` or `Integer` and then skip it respectivly.

Comment: That, or if you want to get creative, create custom `List` that automatically skips first element added, and bind to that type.